# Página não carrega arquivo SCSS

Tags: css, scss

Estou aprendendo desenvolvimento web e comecei mexer com `SCSS` em um layout porém o navegador não está puxando o mesmo. Ele está sendo chamado junto com o arquivo do `CSS` que está funcionando normalmente na página.

```
<link href="css/abert_painel.scss" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../build/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Já a atuação do `SCSS` está sendo nula e recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro no inspector:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por que isso ocorre? Como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: SCSS não deveria ser compilado para um arquivo .css e aí você referenciar este arquivo? (.css)

Comment: Podemos te orientar como instalar ferramentas para fazer a compilação do .scss para .css, qual seu Sistema Operacional? Tem Node? Ruby instalado? Ou pesquisa como compilar .scss

Comment: @David pode sim. Estou utilizando um mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para podermos compilar o arquivo .scss para .css precisa ter instalado o Ruby (essa é uma das formas).

## 1.Verifique se já tem instalado:

```
ruby -v
```

se retornar algo como:

> ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]

Continue, senão [veja aqui como instalar o ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/pt/documentation/installation/#homebrew).

## 2.Instale o sass:

```
sudo gem install sass
```

## 3.Compilando

**3.1 Modo Estático:**
Dessa forma cada vez que tiver uma alteração no .scss tera que digitar a linha de comando abaixo para compilar.

```
sass --update cssfilename.scss
```

ou um diretório:

```
sass --update /directory/
```

**3.2 Dinâmico:**
Dessa forma qualquer alteração feita no .scss é automaticamente convertido para o .css.

```
sass --watch sass cssfilename.scss
```

ou um diretório:

```
sass --watch /directory/
```

Comment: coloquei sass --update abert_painel.scss e me retornou um erro: -bash: sass: command not found

Comment: digita `sass -v`, teria que retornar a versão do SASS instalado.. senão tem que instalar